# Prove that $R/(2i)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R=\{a+2ib|a,b\text{ integers}\}$.Prove that $R/(2i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Can you list some of the elements of the quotient $R/(2i)$?

Comment: I saw that if a is of the form 4k+t(t=1,2,3) then 4k+t=(-2i)(2ik)+t.So a+2ib mod (2i) is actually equal to t mod (2i).But I am not getting the isomorphism

Comment: I want to ask a question here: If i can show there are two homomorphism one from A to B, another B to A, then does Schröder-Bernstein theorem imply , there exists a isomorphism between them ?

Comment: But as far I know you need to have some injective homomorphism to apply bernstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, when trying to show that there exists an isomorphism between a quotient ring $R/I$ and another ring $S$, it is easiest to find a surjective homomorphism $R\to S$ which has kernel $I$, and then to use the isomorphism theorem.

In this case, consider the map
$$\begin{align}R &\to \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\\a+2ib&\mapsto a\pmod 4\end{align}$$

Can you show that this:

- is a homormorphism
- is surjective
- has kernel $(2i)\subset R$